# security concers at nginx proxy_pass

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

If I would run nginx as a proxy and forward all https traffic via proxy_pass to a node.js server that isn't using tls, does this cause a security breach?
The proxy and the node js server would be in the same internal network that is protected by a firewall for instance.

For example the config from nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/tls/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/tls/certificate.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2;
    }
}
```

The ip address in the proxy_pass command could then be the node js server.

Comment: You should have trust in your own data center so it is not a problem. SSL termination at the front proxy is quite common.

Comment: yes, it is security breach, even if it is your internal private network, it does not mean that you should trust all devices in this network

Comment: To trust the whole internal network seems indeed to be a security breach. Is it sufficient to change the forwards to https (proxy_pass https:// 192.168.1.2;)?
Would it be a problem to take the same certificate that is also used for the connection from the client to the proxy?